# \dot over \vec over : amsmath bug/feature?

Tags: amsmath

I was trying to typeset the time derivative of `\vec{r}_\alpha`, and naively, I put it as an argument to `\dot`. This does not work: the arrow is not on `r` anymore. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\dot{\vec{r}_\alpha}
\]
\end{document}
```

Note that there is a better way to typeset it (and it works): `\dot{\vec{r}}_\alpha`. I am asking out of curiosity.

Comment: I'd use all sorts of "beautifiers" (`\dot`, `\hat`, etc.) only on the main symbol (in your case, "r") and not on the whole object (r_\alpha). Unless the `\dot` is e.g. absolute time derivative, or a similar operator that is to be applied on the whole term.

Comment: from physical view it is wrong to have the dot over r _and_ alpha. It should only be over the r, the reason why your own solution is the only correct one.

Comment: @Herbert, I of course agree that the correct thing to do is `\dot{\vec{r}}_\alpha`. I was mostly asking because `amsmath` changes the output unexpectedly.

Comment: you are absolutely right, it should work ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the mattens package. I have written it to "overcome" these problems

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mattens} % use [noformat] for non-bold symbols
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
  $\aS[\Dot]{r}_\alpha$

  or some other examples where \TeX\ makes a real mess on its own

  $\bS[\Dot]{f}^i_j$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmm, again: Can you explain what you mean, please? If I replace `amsmath` with `mattens`, I get the same problems.

Comment: @Hendrik: See the example in updated post

Comment: sorry, which updated post?

Comment: @Bruno: He refers to the code in _this answer_.

Comment: @Hendrik: for some reason the edited post had not appeared yet when I posted my comment. @Danie. Thanks: although your answer does not solve my question of putting a dot on `\vec{r}_\alpha`, it is probably the most useful for future users.

Answer (score 3):

To me it looks like a bug: It works as expected if you omit `\usepackage{amsmath}`. However, it's somewhat strange what you're trying to do. You should *not* expect `\dot{\vec{r}_\alpha}` and `\dot{\vec{r}}_\alpha` to produce the same output; in the first case, the `\dot` should be centered over `\vec{r}_\alpha`, and over `\vec{r}` in the second case:

[image]

And I have no idea *why* you'd want to achieve the first version: If you want the *`\dot`* over everything, then maybe you should also put the *`\vec`* over everything, as in `\dot{\vec{r_\alpha}}`. This again works with `amsmath`.

As to why `amsmath` changes things (see comment below): `amsmath` contains a fix for producing nice double accents, and this seems to go wrong here.
(Incidentally, you get almost the same unexpected behaviour if you use `accents` instead of `amsmath`.)

Comment: I agree with the various comments on the fact that no one should do that, but I was wondering why amsmath changes things. And yes, the outputs should be slightly different, but only moving the dot slightly.

Comment: @Bruno: See my update.