# Mixing "check" and "hat" leads to odd output (using MnSymbol)

Tags: math-mode

I'm trying to typeset a formula that contains the expression `$\check{x} g_1$` underneath a widehat.  However, when I typeset the expression `$\widehat{\check{x} g_1}$`, I get odd results -- the "check" and the `g_1` are in the right places, but the `x` is shifted to the right so that it overlaps with the `g_1` (thus leaving the `check` resting over a blank space).  What am I doing wrong?

EDIT : My one theory is that this has something to do with using the MnSymbol package.  Here's a minimal document that has the problem.

```
\documentclass[11 pt]{article}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\begin{document}

$$\widehat{\check{x} g_1}$$

\end{document}
```

If I omit the MnSymbol package, the problem goes away.

Comment: Can you make a minimal document that duplicates the problem and add that to your question. A quick test doesn't reveal the problem. Are you sure it's not simply a problem with your dvi/pdf viewer?

Comment: @Alan: it could be amsmath. I had the same problem in [this question][1] with dot and vector (and the same rendering as described by Andy). --- [1][http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9669/dot-over-vec-over-amsmath-bug-feature]

Comment: @Bruno I don't think so in this case.  That's why we need a minimal document.  With or without `amsmath` I get a fine output.

Comment: @Alan : I added a minimal document.  While creating it, I think I narrowed down the problem to the MnSymbol package.

Comment: @Alan: sorry, it looked very similar, and I didn't check.

Comment: @Bruno: I'm still slightly puzzled that again we see this strange accent behaviour. There must be some common reason, but I didn't quite get it yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

load
`\usepackage{accents}`
after MnSymbol

Comment: Thanks!  That seems to fix it.  By the way, what exactly does the "accents" package do?

Comment: it corrects the accent setting, especially for doubled accents

Answer (score 2):

Herbert gave you a perfect solution; I'll try and explain a bit what's going wrong. Let me begin by saying that it's easy to reproduce the odd output with `amsmath` (see also the comments to the question). In amsmath.sty, there are the lines

```
%%\@tempa\widetilde
%%\@tempa\widehat
```

and it's indeed good that they're commented out. `\@tempa` is a command that gives accents a special treatment for better accent positioning, especially for double accents. (Compare Herbert's comment to his answer.) This treatment is given to all the "small" accents, including `\check`.

Now the following code gives the same odd output as the OP's code.

```
\documentclass[11 pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\@tempa\widehat
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\[ \widehat{\check{x} g_1} \]
\end{document}
```

This might explain why `\@tempa\widehat` is commented out in amsmath.sty.

---

Now `MnSymbol` loads `amsmath` and then calls

```
\DeclareMathAccent{\widehat}{\mathord}{largesymbols}{’302}
```

which in turn calls `\set@mathaccent`. But this is the modified `\set@mathaccent` from `amsmath`, so thing again go wrong. A possible fix is to give `\widehat` a LaTeX type definition back again, but for this you have to know the accent number `"3C2`:

```
\documentclass[11 pt]{article}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\show\widehat
\def\widehat{\mathaccent"3C2\relax}
\begin{document}
\[ \widehat{\check{x} g_1} \]
\end{document}
```

Summarizing: To me it looks like a bug in `MnSymbol`.