# amsmath possible bug: \dot over bracketed \dot{x}

Tags: amsmath

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [\dot over \vec over : amsmath bug/feature?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9669/dot-over-vec-over-amsmath-bug-feature)

Is this a bug (I can't see it reported anywhere)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\dot{[\dot{x}]}
\]
\end{document}
```

produces a misaligned "x" whereas without the `\usepackage{amsmath}` the alignment is fine.

Comment: Have a look at [\dot over \vec over : amsmath bug/feature?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9669/dot-over-vec-over-amsmath-bug-feature).

Comment: What mathematical/physical object are you trying to represent? How are readers supposed to understand that the outer `\dot` applies to `[\dot{x}]` rather than simply the inner `\dot{x}`?