# Math-accent symbol over parentheses enclosing accented symbol (amsmath)

Tags: amsmath, accents

I'm trying to write an expression in which an accented expression enclosed by parentheses has an accent over the parentheses. For example,

```
\vec{(\dot{x})}
```

This typesets fine when amsmath is not loaded, but with amsmath present, the x is typeset to the right of the dot, as if the inner expression is being treated as

```
\dot{}x
```

This behavior only happens when a closing parentheses (or bracket or brace) is part of the argument to the outer accent.

The best workaround I've been able to find is to use overset for the outer accent instead of the actual accent command (or accentset).

Is this behavior expected/documented anywhere?

---

I believe that this question was previously asked at 
[amsmath possible bug: \dot over bracketed \dot{x}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43185/amsmath-possible-bug-dot-over-bracketed-dotx?noredirect=1&lq=1), but was incorrectly marked as a duplicate of [\dot over \vec over : amsmath bug/feature?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9669/dot-over-vec-over-amsmath-bug-feature). The latter question was about the differences in typesetting between dotting a subscripted character and subscripting a dotted character.

Comment: I guess this is rather related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30327/4427. On the other hand, `(\vec{\dot{x})` seems better syntax.

Comment: Thanks. On the syntax question, putting the parentheses outside the \vec command is semantically different from applying the \vec to the whole contents of the parentheses. My \vec{(\dot{x})} minimal example probably would not be used in practice, but applying accents to parenthetically-delimited expressions or to matrices has multiple use-cases.

Comment: How's the reader supposed to know the difference between `\vec{(\dot{x})}` and `(\vec{\dot{x}})`? And, if you have `\vec{(blahblah)}` the problem is even worse.

Comment: As I said, I don't think that my minimal example will be used in practice. An expression like \dot{\begin{bmatrix} x \\ \dot{x} \end{bmatrix}} has a use-case (in explaining basic controls systems principles), and gets mangled by this bug. As a second example, in \vec{(\exp \dot{x})} vs (\vec{\exp \dot{x}}), the \vec is set higher on the first expression, clearly indicating that it applies to the contents of the parentheses.

Comment: Funny thing, I wrote a package to shift the accents of `\mathaccentV` (the macro `amsmath` uses internally for `\dot`, etc.), which doesn't suffer from this issue. I'll try to provide a patch from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do with a long-standing `amsmath` issue, see [Why do arguments to nested \tilde or \breve commands reappear when amsmath is used?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30327/4427)

I can offer a workaround.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\dblacc}[2]{\mathpalette\dblacc@{{#1}{#2}}}
\newcommand{\dblacc@}[2]{\dblacc@@#1#2}
\newcommand{\dblacc@@}[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1#3$}%
  #2{\box\z@}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\dblacc\vec{(\dot{x})}
\\
\dblacc\dot{\begin{bmatrix} x \\ \dot{x} \end{bmatrix}}
\\
\dblacc\vec{(\exp \dot{x})}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A version that works also with `accents`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\dblacc@boxa}
\newsavebox{\dblacc@boxb}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\dblacc}[2]{\mathpalette\dblacc@{{#1}{#2}}}
\newcommand{\dblacc@}[2]{\dblacc@@#1#2}
\newcommand{\dblacc@@}[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\dblacc@boxa{$\m@th#1#3$}%
  \sbox\dblacc@boxb{$\m@th#1#2{\copy\dblacc@boxa}$}%
  \box\dblacc@boxb
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\dblacc\vec{(\dot{x})}\quad\scriptscriptstyle\dblacc\vec{(\dot{x})}
\\
\dblacc\dot{\begin{bmatrix} x \\ \dot{x} \end{bmatrix}}
\\
\dblacc\vec{(\exp \dot{x})}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. If it's not too much trouble, is there a way to make this compatible with the accents package? I'm using the \accentset command in my document for a custom accent, and with the accents package turned on, the arguments to the outer accent all disappear.

Comment: @RLH `\newcommand{\myaccent}[1]{\accentset{<accent>}{#1}}` and `\dblacc\myaccent{whatever}` should work

Comment: Sorry for the miscommunication: The problem I'm running into is that if I add \usepackage{accents} to the preamble of the example document you posted, only the outer accent character appears -- the rest of the expression is not typeset.

Comment: @RLH Problem solved. `:-D`

Answer (score 5):

The following redefines an internal of `amsmath`. After that the output of your example looks good. I don't know whether this has any possibility of breaking other stuff. I've added every test case egreg used in his answer and the output looks good. It doesn't work with the `accents` package, though.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[]{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\protected\def\mathaccentV#1#2#3#4#5%
  {%
    \ifmmode
      \mathaccentV@do{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}%
    \else
      \@xp\nonmatherr@\csname #1\endcsname
    \fi
  }
\def\mathaccentV@do#1#2#3#4%
  {%
    \global\let\macc@nucleus\@empty
    \mathaccent"\accentclass@#1#2#3{#4}\macc@nucleus
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\vec{(\dot{x})}
\\
\dot{\begin{bmatrix} x \\ \dot{x} \end{bmatrix}}
\\
\vec{(\exp \dot{x})}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much. Is there something fundamental about the accents package that breaks solutions of the kind that you and egreg suggested?

Comment: @RLH `accents` redefines all those accents macros to no longer use `\mathaccentV`, so my fix is bound to not work there. I didn't dig too deep into why the `accents` package fails to do the alignment right, so I can't really state anything else about the issue.

Comment: Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @RLH note that this patch changes the way `\vec{\dot{x}}` would be typeset (the arrow is moved slightly to the right which yields imperfect placement, but not severely misplacement). In the original use case of my package where something like this is done, that is not that bad, because the default placement of the accents would be very bad there.

Comment: @RLH if you only use `accents` for `\accentset`, you can use the package option `single`. That way my fix above will still be applied.

Comment: +1 for the disclaimer alone.

Comment: Thanks once more for your help. I like that this one does not need new in-document syntax, but I'm able to get more consistent results with custom accents using egreg's suggestion. I'd accept both answers if I could.