# Nested \dot collides with amsmath

Tags: amsmath

when using \dot in a nested manner, the letter in the middle is not centered anymore. Why does it happen?

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$\dot{(\dot{s} )}$
\end{document}
```

Is there any solution to this appart from not using `amsmath`?

[image]

EDIT:
Thank you for the answers, I used this which helps also to keep the formula still readable if it gets more complex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newsavebox{\dotbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\outerdot}[1]{\sbox\dotbox{$#1$}\dot{\usebox\dotbox}}
\begin{document}
$\outerdot{\left(\dot{s} \right )}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `(\dot{\dot{s}})`?

Comment: This issue seems very related to the one I ran into in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482281/math-accent-symbol-over-parentheses-enclosing-accented-symbol-amsmath .  Answers there might be relevant.

Comment: Thanks thats a very good link!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the inner `\dot` in a `\box`.  Then outer `\dot` the `\box`.

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\setbox0=\hbox{$(\dot{s} )$}
$\dot{\box0}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Or you can use `accents` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}

\begin{document}
$(\accentset{:}{s})$
\end{document}
```

Or with option bold (`bm` package),

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
$(\accentset{\bm{:}}{s})$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ingenious! (+1)

Comment: @Bernard Naaaaaaaa :-) (similar to noooooo :-))